# Erro do Sqlite no Android : error code 11: database disk image is malformed

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho uma versão do Aplicativo em produção, onde é permitido marcar uma mensagem como favorita, só que esse erro totalmente aleatório acontece provocando corrompimento da base de dados e resultando em falha do aplicativo.

Sei que realizo [operações um pouco arriscadas](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) segundo o próprio pessoal da SQLite.

O procedimento é o seguinte:

- inicia o procedimento de upgrade
- copia a base de dados do usuário para um arquivo temporário
- copia a nova base de dados para o dispositivo
- anexa a base antiga com a nova
- copia-se dados necessários (como as mensagens favoritas)
- desanexa a base temporária
- exclui a base temporária

Esse procedimento é feito em milhares de dispositivos, na maioria tudo ocorre bem, mas começou a se tornar frequentes casos assim.

Alguém sabe como minimizar isso?

ERRO:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.redrails.torpedos/br.com.redrails.torpedos.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: error code 11: database disk image is malformed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: error code 11: database disk image is malformed
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_1x1_long(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong(SQLiteStatement.java:138)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:791)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:779)
    at br.com.redrails.torpedos.MensagemDAO.reloadQuantidadeTotal(MensagemDAO.java:144)
    at br.com.redrails.torpedos.MensagemDAO.getQuantidadeTotal(MensagemDAO.java:149)
    at br.com.redrails.torpedos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Talvez bloquear acesso ao banco de dados antes de fazer essas operações?

Comment: Achas que bloqueando a base irá solucionar? e outra eu preciso efetuar operações na base de dados durante o processo.

Comment: Talvez bote as operações numa fila, bloqueie durante o copiar, daí desbloqueie e continue com a fila... escrever para um arquivo que nesse momento é copiado dá problemas de qq forma, pq n é atómico.

Comment: Por acaso ainda li código hoje que me confirmou que no Sqlite isso é importante... (e sugeriu ainda que as vezes bloqueio do lado do programa pode nem bastar...)

Comment: Sabe onde posso conseguir mais explicações de como realizar isso @LaPingvino ??

Comment: http://www.mimec.org/node/306 talvez isso já ajuda para bloqueiar no nível de sqlite mesmo, senão também tem como bloqueiar no Java (veja sobre threading).

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado @LaPingvino :)

Comment: Seria muito bom um exemplo de código das operações que você está fazendo.

Você está tentando mexer na base enquanto copia?

Manipula em diferentes threads ao mesmo tempo?

Quais operações arrostadas que eles citam, que você está realizando?

Comment: Modifiquei para tentar minizar tudo, vou adicionar o exemplo do código @AlexandreR.L.eMarcondes

Comment: Uma coisa que percebo os desenvolvedores se esquecerem em dispositivos Android é que estes normalmente possuem memórias secundárias de estado sólido como Flash, e que estas possuem um número de ciclos de escrita restrito (o próprio Windows Embbeded possuiu opção para reduzir o número de escritas), portanto o quanto mais puder trabalhar na memória primaria (RAM) antes de escrever na secundária melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns meses começamos a receber muitos relatos de usuários queixando-se de falhas em um de nossos aplicativos. Durante a investigação do problema, ficou claro que o erro era decorrente de alguma corrupção no arquivo do `SQLite`. Observei que esse problema passou a existir também de um certo período para até então. Vi ainda que esse erro ocorria em especial com dispositivos mais novos que possuem mais núcleos de processamento e maior clock e que em dispositivos mais antigos menos potentes e em especial com apenas um núcleo esse erro ocorria muito pouco ou simplesmente não ocorria. Isso me fez concluir que o problema era relativo a concorrência. Que aqui estava ligado ao acesso por multiplas Threads ao `SQLite`.

Depois de alguma pesquisa e testes vi os seguintes pontos:

Para cada banco de dados apenas deve existir apenas um  `SqliteOpenHelper`.
Por mais que pareça, não existem múltiplas conexões com o banco de dados. Um  `SqliteOpenHelper` possui apenas uma conexão. Sempre. Mesmo que os métodos `getWritableDatabase` e `getReadableDatabase` faça parecer que existem duas conexões diferentes, isso simplesmente não acontece: é a mesma conexão.

Isso garante que não ocorra colisões, acessos concorrentes, ao arquivo do banco de dados.

No caso do aplicativo em questão, havia múltiplos `SqliteOpenHelper` e múltiplas Threads. A solução foi um refactoring geral na persistência com o objetivo haver apenas um  `SqliteOpenHelper` para cada banco de dados (no caso havia três). Houve assim uma forte redução nas ocorrências do problema, todavia ainda houve ocorrências.

Finalmente, foram sincronizados os métodos de acesso ao banco de dados de forma a evitar o acesso concorrente ao  `SqliteOpenHelper`. Essa é foi uma medida que não afetou o desempenho do aplicativo, mas que porém deve ser analisada para cada caso.

Resumindo:

1. Mantenha apenas um  `SqliteOpenHelper` por banco de dados
2. Se necessário e viável, sincronize o acesso

Comment: Resposta bastante completa, ainda não cheguei a testar, mas o cenário parece uma descrição fiel do meu. Deste modo creio que seja a solução que devo implementar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é valido estudar a possibilidade de implementar um serviço PUSH para sincronizar teus bancos de dados, assim tudo seria feito de forma "invisível"  ao usuário e também de forma mais segura.

Um bom lugar para criar WS gratuitos e também utilizar PUSH gratuito tanto para Android quanto iOS é http://parse.com